# Null Pointer Exception from JCalander Combobox

Tags: java, date, calendar, datepicker

My Java Application produces Null Pointer Exception from JCalander Combobox. I tried to catch the error. But that didnt work. Can someone assist me to fix this. Please.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1106)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:955)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:948)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:336)
at org.freixas.jcalendar.JCalendarCombo.paramString(JCalendarCombo.java:780)
at java.awt.Component.toString(Component.java:8095)


 tbmodel = (DefaultTableModel)tblItmQty.getModel();
        System.out.println(calRecvDate.getDate());
        try{
        if(calRecvDate.getDate()==null){ // Error
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select Shippment Received Date");  
            calRecvDate.requestFocus();

        }else if(txtShipSs.getText().isEmpty()){
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  if (inputValidate() == true) {

              try {
                    String shipId = txtShipId.getText();
                    String invID = txtInvoice.getText();
                    String shipSs = txtShipSs.getText();
                    String address = txtNtfAddress.getText();
                    String sipper = txtAShipper.getText();
                    String vessal = txtVessal.getText();
                    Date rcvDate = calRecvDate.getDate(); // Jcalander
                    String consignee = txtConsigne.getText();


                    ArrayList<ShippmentItems> shipItems = new ArrayList<ShippmentItems>();
                    tbmodel = (DefaultTableModel) tblItmQty.getModel();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tbmodel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                          String itmcode = (String) tbmodel.getValueAt(i, 0);
                          String itmName = (String) tbmodel.getValueAt(i, 1);
                          int qty = (int) tbmodel.getValueAt(i, 2);
                          ShippmentItems shpItems = new ShippmentItems(shipId, itmcode, itmName, qty);
                          shipItems.add(shpItems);
                    }
```

Comment: Never catch a NullPointerException but instead find the line of code that causes it, find out which variable on that line is null, and then trace back into your code to see why it has not been initialized. If you need more of our help, you'll have to tell us more and show us more including showing us your pertinent code, telling us which line is the offending line, which variable is null, and where you *think* you're initializing this variable.

Comment: @Reimeus Original code updated.

Comment: I set the selected index to -1 as i want form load with date unselected.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels Updated the code.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels -  if(calRecvDate.getDate()==null){

Comment: When I press the ADD button without selecting date, program pop ups with message "Please Select Shippment Received Date", after that i get null pointer error

Comment: I'm frankly surprised that `System.out.println(calRecvDate.getDate());` doesn't throw the NPE since it is called before the line you've indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this throws the NPE:

```
calRecvDate.getDate()==null
```

The `calRecvDate` variable is null, and you will either need to check if it's null before using it, or make sure that it isn't null by tracing back in your code to where you think you've initialized it and fix the problem (since it isn't initialized).

To check if it's null, you could do:

```
if (calRecvDate != null) {
  // use the calRecvDate variable here
} else {
  // initialize the calRecvDate variable here

  // or perhaps better, display a JOptionPane error message to the user
  // that the date hasn't been selected, and exit this method by calling return:

  return;
}
```

Again, don't use try/catch blocks to handle NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: When I press the ADD button without selecting date, program pop ups with message "Please Select Shippment Received Date", after that i get null pointer error. I ll update the Save button's code above. For me it seems date time format error. Could you check again.

Comment: Thanks Lot. I ll try and let you know.

Comment: Thanx Lot. It worked. I did the initialization above If condition.