# I am getting a NullPointer exception in a java program

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, simpledateformat

Hi I am getting a Nullpointer error when I run my program. I found a post on this site that I thought would fix the problem [Null Pointer Exception from JCalander Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851873/null-pointer-exception-from-jcalander-combobox) I used the suggestions from this page but am still getting the error. Could someone please tell me where I went wrong?

```
    String end;
    if (jTimeButton3 != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatTime2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        end = dateFormatTime2.format(jTimeButton3.getTargetDate());
        endTime.setText(end);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Please select a End Time.");

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Post a stacktrace, and complete your code, please?

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The error is at the 4th line of this code

Comment: @Reimeus More like jTimeButton3.getTargetDate() is null. He already did a null check on jTimeButton3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a NullPointerException because your `jTimeButton3.getTargetDate()` is Null:

You can fix it by testing your date:

```
String end;
if (jTimeButton3 != null && jTimeButton3.getTargetDate() != null) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatTime2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    end = dateFormatTime2.format(jTimeButton3.getTargetDate());
    endTime.setText(end);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, "Please select a End Time.");

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good except that you should put a check for your endTime reference, it may be null and you are calling setText on it. Put a null pointer check around it to nail the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a good look at your code reveals the almost 100 percent candidate for being NPE:

Here is your code:

```
String end;
    if (jTimeButton3 != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatTime2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        end = dateFormatTime2.format(jTimeButton3.getTargetDate());
        endTime.setText(end);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Please select a End Time.");

        return;
    }
```

jTimeButton3 is not throwing NPE since you are checking in the `if` statement, `dateFomatTime2` is != null too, meaning that `endTime` is our candidate left, so I'll advice you to post the other part of the code.

**Note**: This answer is useful only if you are certain that the NPE is in the piece of code you are posting